# D3 show segment of series data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm looking for advice on how to tackle the following chart in D3.js:

[image: Proposed chart]

I have data in the following format for the 7 series shown

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║ Learning Disability  ║
╠══════════════════════╣
║ AgeBand | Percentage ║
║ 0-4     | 0.02       ║
║ 5-9     | 0.01       ║
║ 10-14   | 0.015      ║
║ ...     | ...        ║
║ 75+     | 75+        ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

I would like the slider to snap to the 16 'age bands', and on slideEnd transition each series bar. So only the 7 series values from one age band is shown at a time.

What would be the most straightforward way of only showing 1 segment from a series of values, and separating each series into it's own bar?

Comment: was worried I'd get shot down for not being specific enough

Comment: sorry I'll ask over there instead

Comment: @AlasdairC "too broad" is a close reason at both sites. Regardless, this question was migrated so it is now in the right place (broad/specific concerns aside).

Answer (score 0):

> only showing 1 segment from a series of values

series are arrays, so given:

```
var x1 = ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 6, 65]
```

use `concat` to get one value plus the label. For example:

```
var x1_segment = [].concat(x1[0],x1[2]) // [ "data1", 200 ]
```

> separating each series into it's own bar

```
svg.selectAll("rect").enter();

svg.append("rect").data(x1_segment).attr("x", transformX).attr("y", 0);

svg.selectAll("rect").attr("width", "20");
```

**References**

- [Data visualization, Part 2: Use D3 component layouts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-dataviz2/)